# Does laptop model matter in LCD Screen cable?

Tags: laptop, display, cable

OK, the situation is this. I have two different laptops (different brands), and both of them have the same screen size. Also the LCD screen cable is the same physically, I've tried to plug the LCD screen cable of the first laptop on the second one, and it fits right in.
Now, I haven't tried to power it on as I'm afraid that being different brands will cause any problem.
Is it okay to try to power the second laptop on with the LCD screen cable of the first laptop in this case?

Comment: There is no way we can tell you who manufactures either of the screens and as a result no way we can tell you if they have the same interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cant be 100% certain without knowing the motherboard and LCD model and revision and someone taking the time to see if the pin-outs and voltages are identical.

Most laptop manufacturers do not make their own parts.  The source them from other manufacturers.  There are also standards which most adhere to.  So if it fits, then personally, I would be fine with plugging it in and turning it on